# What is the maximum quality score in a VCF file

Tags: bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

Does anybody know if the maximum VCF quality score is explicitly defined somewhere?

Thanks in advance :)

I have a VCF file containing roughly 8.3 million variations. I was wondering if there is a limit to the quality score in the VCF file. The highest I found was a quality of 999. Roughly 20% of my VCF file has this 999 quality score, so I am assuming that this is the maximum. I'm just not sure and want to use this information for my graduation thesis.

Comment: Related: https://www.biostars.org/p/62387/

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum value for quality defined within the vcf specification https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf and all of the different variant callers will manage this differently. This is however not a problem in practice because one would never be applying filters at such high levels of confidence. The real question you should be asking is what is the lowest quality score that I am prepared to accept. Unfortunately there is no universal answer to this question as it depends on the sequencing technology, pipeline and application. That being said, filtering out variants with a quality score of less than 30 is a common strategy that works well in a variety of scenarios and it would be uncommon to use a value significantly higher than this.